# How to access IBM Tivoli logs for a Job?

Tags: tivoli, tivoli-work-scheduler

I need to access the logs in Tivoli when a job fails but I don't know the steps. Can some one please let me know the steps on how to access the logs?

Tivoli version is 8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to Tivoli Workload Scheduler, it actually includes 2 different products: "Tivoli Workload Scheduler" and "Tivoli Workload Scheduler for z/OS", both can run workload on distributed and mainframe platforms, the first controls the workload from a UNIX or Windows server, the second from a z/OS server.

In both cases you can access the job logs from the web UI (known as Dynamic Workload Console): run Monitor Workload to list jobs or job streams you are interested, in case you start from the job stream select the job stream you want to see and click on jobs to list the jobs of the stream. Then select the job you want to see the log and click on "Job Log"

On "Tivoli Workload Scheduler" you can do the same operation also from `conman` command line: `conman "sj <jobselector>; stdlist"`

On "Tivoli Workload Scheduler for z/OS" you can use the ISPF panels to list operations (jobs) and request the joblog.

In case of "Tivoli Workload Scheduler for z/OS" be aware that in order to get logs of jobs running on z/OS you have to run also the optional datastore started task.

Both products also provides several different APIs to retrieve the job logs.